# B violation and electric charge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-anomalies, electroweak, baryons

Within SM you can prove that despite we have baryon number conservation respect to Noether theorem, at quantum level baryon (and lepton) number is violated as

$$
\Delta B = 3·\Delta n_{CS}, \quad n_{CS} \in \mathbb{Z}\ ({\rm Chern-Simons\ index\ for\ vacuum})
\tag1$$

So, I've been  thinking: if $B$ is violated, is this implying that electric charge isn't conserved? And I have a technical question on this $B$: is it defined as

$$
B = \frac{N_q - N_{\bar{q}}}{3}, \quad {\rm or}\quad B = N_q - N_{\bar{q}}\ ?
$$

At tree level, Feynman diagrams grant conservation but I can imagine a triangle diagram with a loop made with a fermion, $f$, that produces a $Z^0$, goes on the loop and destroys with its antipaticle given as a result another $Z^0$ boson (see image below). Since this vertices contain left and right projectors, then they give an anomaly such as the chiral anomaly.

In the picture,

$$
\sum_f = \sum_{all\ quarks\\within\ SM}
$$

---

[image: Triangle diagramas]

Comment: I'm not sure how your triangle diagram is relevant to your question, since neither of $\gamma, Z^0$ are electrically charged.

Comment: @ACuriousMind What should I use?